# Como obter o R² e a equação da curva plotada a partir do objeto criado pela função MOStest

Tags: r

No **R**, eu rodei a **função MOStest** do **pacote vegan** para verificar se a relação entre duas variáveis tinha o formato de corcunda. Até aí tudo certo, verifiquei que de fato a curva tinha este formato e gerei o gráfico com a função plot. Agora eu preciso obter o **R² do ajuste quadrático** e a **equação da curva**, como eu posso fazer? Tem como sair a equação com base nos dados?

Eu não encontrei estas informações dando um summary. Este é o script:

```
mod <- MOStest(PET, Riqueza, family=gaussian)

summary(mod)

plot(mod)
```

Conforme foi solicitado, a fim de permitir a replicação, reproduzo aqui o resultado da função dput sobre o objeto "mod" gerado no script acima. Reitero que não se trata de um erro, o script rodou perfeitamente, o meu problema se trata de como conseguir duas informações nos resultados, o R2 e a equação da curva. Segue o resultado do dput:

```
dput(mod)
structure(list(isHump = TRUE, isBracketed = TRUE, hump = c(min = 1087, 
hump = 1258.31714127466, max = 1750), family = structure(list(
    family = "gaussian", link = "identity", linkfun = function (mu) 
    mu, linkinv = function (eta) 
    eta, variance = function (mu) 
    rep.int(1, length(mu)), dev.resids = function (y, mu, wt) 
    wt * ((y - mu)^2), aic = function (y, n, mu, wt, dev) 
    {
        nobs <- length(y)
        nobs * (log(dev/nobs * 2 * pi) + 1) + 2 - sum(log(wt))
    }, mu.eta = function (eta) 
    rep.int(1, length(eta)), initialize = expression({
        n <- rep.int(1, nobs)
        if (is.null(etastart) && is.null(start) && is.null(mustart) && 
            ((family$link == "inverse" && any(y == 0)) || (family$link == 
                "log" && any(y <= 0)))) 
            stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some")
        mustart <- y
    }), validmu = function (mu) 
    TRUE, valideta = function (eta) 
    TRUE), class = "family"), coefficients = structure(list(`min/max` = c(1087, 
1750, NA), F = c(1.47951715715753, 8.32257715767822, NA), `Pr(>F)` = c(0.240469622558875, 
0.0102866435223026, 0.248282640795972)), row.names = c("hump at min", 
"hump at max", "Combined"), class = "data.frame"), mod = structure(list(
    coefficients = c(`(Intercept)` = -610.411556247032, x = 1.27173798958452, 
    `I(x^2)` = -0.000505332856030344), residuals = c(`1` = -19.0903389236728, 
    `2` = 36.2323157794438, `3` = 32.4967819365999, `4` = -28.6873895737368, 
    `5` = 16.1646964784381, `6` = 10.7498764032539, `7` = 52.5163341100767, 
    `8` = -4.88200106442309, `9` = 23.1179989355769, `10` = -29.4749022142456, 
    `11` = 26.47737929651, `12` = 33.9294745606495, `13` = -18.8467120784045, 
    `14` = 24.957850571315, `15` = -17.8286205965798, `16` = -9.1830694159712, 
    `17` = -10.6595101557635, `18` = -84.994718570696, `19` = -47.4473915454337, 
    `20` = 14.451946067051), fitted.values = c(`1` = 132.090338923673, 
    `2` = 165.767684220556, `3` = 176.5032180634, `4` = 187.687389573737, 
    `5` = 188.835303521562, `6` = 141.250123596746, `7` = 189.483665889923, 
    `8` = 174.882001064423, `9` = 174.882001064423, `10` = 181.474902214246, 
    `11` = 183.52262070349, `12` = 187.07052543935, `13` = 186.846712078404, 
    `14` = 179.042149428685, `15` = 184.82862059658, `16` = 185.183069415971, 
    `17` = 189.659510155764, `18` = 187.994718570696, `19` = 133.447391545434, 
    `20` = 67.548053932949), effects = c(`(Intercept)` = -759.815898754429, 
    x = 106.275663892188, `I(x^2)` = -78.0307813641536, -19.2473885023306, 
    16.6345964780407, 6.14597586854161, 57.896572949065, 17.8854812803235, 
    45.8854812803235, -33.4235587888267, 23.1930390208033, 44.3212539743377, 
    -8.13125523356534, 44.136777943802, -4.52502693883779, -11.7480403942007, 
    -6.23860669678687, -76.0710038322058, -51.2562947790223, 
    21.0033178425398), R = structure(c(-4.47213595499958, 0, 
    0, -5926.92178116094, -833.327186643997, 0, -8010229.64428267, 
    -2307488.00713431, 154414.62084442), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("(Intercept)", "x", "I(x^2)"), c("(Intercept)", "x", 
        "I(x^2)"))), rank = 3L, qr = structure(list(qr = structure(c(-4.47213595499958, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 0.223606797749979, 
    0.223606797749979, -5926.92178116094, -833.327186643997, 
    0.0542778401641913, -0.215724151377843, -0.0897232219915606, 
    0.231879150156285, -0.16532377962333, -0.34532510731802, 
    -0.34532510731802, 0.0134775392200616, -0.00692261125200326, 
    -0.226524231039525, -0.230124257593419, -0.314124877184274, 
    -0.257724461173271, -0.0261227528727702, -0.152123682259053, 
    -0.209724107121354, 0.260679362587436, 0.450280761092509, 
    -8010229.64428267, -2307488.00713431, 154414.62084442, 0.0613632736741654, 
    0.225096497148415, -0.00436787233684219, 0.143992246106897, 
    -0.256023572028568, -0.256023572028568, 0.25282586685686, 
    0.254940910739639, 0.0406845488494826, 0.0335585020297847, 
    -0.165808644983827, -0.0249472138599037, 0.253512174952593, 
    0.161857618246654, 0.0723981291840941, -0.0703012237387962, 
    -0.690588342533872), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
        "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
        "20"), c("(Intercept)", "x", "I(x^2)"))), rank = 3L, 
        qraux = c(1.22360679774998, 1.12147833583688, 1.23736627251662
        ), pivot = 1:3, tol = 1e-11), class = "qr"), family = structure(list(
        family = "gaussian", link = "identity", linkfun = function (mu) 
        mu, linkinv = function (eta) 
        eta, variance = function (mu) 
        rep.int(1, length(mu)), dev.resids = function (y, mu, 
            wt) 
        wt * ((y - mu)^2), aic = function (y, n, mu, wt, dev) 
        {
            nobs <- length(y)
            nobs * (log(dev/nobs * 2 * pi) + 1) + 2 - sum(log(wt))
        }, mu.eta = function (eta) 
        rep.int(1, length(eta)), initialize = expression({
            n <- rep.int(1, nobs)
            if (is.null(etastart) && is.null(start) && is.null(mustart) && 
                ((family$link == "inverse" && any(y == 0)) || 
                  (family$link == "log" && any(y <= 0)))) 
                stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some")
            mustart <- y
        }), validmu = function (mu) 
        TRUE, valideta = function (eta) 
        TRUE), class = "family"), linear.predictors = c(`1` = 132.090338923673, 
    `2` = 165.767684220556, `3` = 176.5032180634, `4` = 187.687389573737, 
    `5` = 188.835303521562, `6` = 141.250123596746, `7` = 189.483665889923, 
    `8` = 174.882001064423, `9` = 174.882001064423, `10` = 181.474902214246, 
    `11` = 183.52262070349, `12` = 187.07052543935, `13` = 186.846712078404, 
    `14` = 179.042149428685, `15` = 184.82862059658, `16` = 185.183069415971, 
    `17` = 189.659510155764, `18` = 187.994718570696, `19` = 133.447391545434, 
    `20` = 67.548053932949), deviance = 21148.4804239745, aic = 204.029362543648, 
    null.deviance = 38531.8, iter = 2L, weights = c(`1` = 1, 
    `2` = 1, `3` = 1, `4` = 1, `5` = 1, `6` = 1, `7` = 1, `8` = 1, 
    `9` = 1, `10` = 1, `11` = 1, `12` = 1, `13` = 1, `14` = 1, 
    `15` = 1, `16` = 1, `17` = 1, `18` = 1, `19` = 1, `20` = 1
    ), prior.weights = c(`1` = 1, `2` = 1, `3` = 1, `4` = 1, 
    `5` = 1, `6` = 1, `7` = 1, `8` = 1, `9` = 1, `10` = 1, `11` = 1, 
    `12` = 1, `13` = 1, `14` = 1, `15` = 1, `16` = 1, `17` = 1, 
    `18` = 1, `19` = 1, `20` = 1), df.residual = 17L, df.null = 19L, 
    y = c(`1` = 113L, `2` = 202L, `3` = 209L, `4` = 159L, `5` = 205L, 
    `6` = 152L, `7` = 242L, `8` = 170L, `9` = 198L, `10` = 152L, 
    `11` = 210L, `12` = 221L, `13` = 168L, `14` = 204L, `15` = 167L, 
    `16` = 176L, `17` = 179L, `18` = 103L, `19` = 86L, `20` = 82L
    ), converged = TRUE, boundary = FALSE, model = structure(list(
        y = c(113L, 202L, 209L, 159L, 205L, 152L, 242L, 170L, 
        198L, 152L, 210L, 221L, 168L, 204L, 167L, 176L, 179L, 
        103L, 86L, 82L), x = c(1596L, 1476L, 1420L, 1195L, 1300L, 
        1568L, 1237L, 1087L, 1087L, 1386L, 1369L, 1186L, 1183L, 
        1113L, 1160L, 1353L, 1248L, 1200L, 1592L, 1750L), `I(x^2)` = structure(c(2547216, 
        2178576, 2016400, 1428025, 1690000, 2458624, 1530169, 
        1181569, 1181569, 1920996, 1874161, 1406596, 1399489, 
        1238769, 1345600, 1830609, 1557504, 1440000, 2534464, 
        3062500), class = "AsIs")), terms = y ~ x + I(x^2), row.names = c(NA, 
    20L), class = "data.frame"), call = glm(formula = y ~ x + 
        I(x^2), family = ..1), formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), terms = y ~ 
        x + I(x^2), data = <environment>, offset = NULL, control = list(
        epsilon = 1e-08, maxit = 25, trace = FALSE), method = "glm.fit", 
    contrasts = NULL, xlevels = structure(list(), .Names = character(0))), class = c("glm", 
"lm"))), class = "MOStest")
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Os dados compartilhados não permitem a reprodução do objeto. Estou recebendo o erro `Error: unexpected ')' in "                                                                                                                                                                                       "` quando tento replicar em meu computador. Recomendo copiar novamente o output de `dput(mod)` e testá-lo em uma sessão nova do `R`, sem nenhum objeto na memória. Rode `rm(list = ls())` para limpar a memória do `R` e tente reproduzir o seu próprio exemplo para garantir que funcionará para outros usuários.

Comment: Marcus, obrigado por sua resposta. Não consegui fazer o output funcionar, como a análise roda com um banco de dados pequeno, é mais fácil eu postar os dados aqui para permitir a reprodução:

library(vegan)


X <- c(1596, 1476, 1420, 1195, 1300, 1568, 1237, 1087, 1087, 1386, 1369, 1186, 1183, 1113, 1160, 1353, 1248, 1200, 1592, 1750)
Y <- c(113, 202, 209, 159, 205, 152, 242, 170, 198, 152, 210, 221, 168, 204, 167, 176, 179, 103, 86, 82)
modXY <- MOStest(X, Y, family=gaussian)

##Para juntar os 4 gráficos numa única imagem
op <- par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(4,4,1,1)+.1)

plot(modXY)

Comment: Marcus, quando copiei e colei o script acima, não sei porque ele juntou tudo ignorando as entradas de parágrafos, então ficou com um aspecto desorganizado, e não está assim no script original. Eu não sei porquê ocorreu isso, tentei arrumar mas não consegui fazer as mudanças de linha.

Answer (score 1):

Como sua dúvida não depende especificadamente das suas medidas, vou usar dados simulados genéricos para facilitar a reprodução por outros usuários:

```
set.seed(86)
x <- sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE)  + rnorm(100, 0, 10)
y <- (-6 + 1.2*x - .5*x^2) + rnorm(100, 0, 20)
```

Confira a ajuda da MOStest, ela faz uma chamada para glm com uma função quadrática (y = a + b.x + c.x²).

```
library(vegan)

most <- MOStest(x, y)

> summary(most)
            Length Class      Mode
isHump        1     -none-     logical
isBracketed   1     -none-     logical
hump          3     -none-     numeric
family       11     family     list
coefficients  3     data.frame list
mod          30     glm        list

> formula(most$mod) # ou most$mod$formula
y ~ x + I(x^2)
<environment: 0x56193a7abfc0>

> coef(most$mod) # ou most$mod$coefficients
(Intercept)           x      I(x^2)
 -5.5864792   1.0073143  -0.4913561
```

Quanto ao R², ele não existe no objeto (pode conferir com `str(most)`). Isso porque ele só serve como medida de qualidade de ajuste quando se usa quadrados mínimos ordinários, o que não é o caso de Modelos Lineares Generalizados.

Pode calcular um "pseudo-R²"; no caso de um GLM com família Gaussiana e link identidade, uma medida equivalente é:

```
> with(summary(most$mod), 1 - deviance/null.deviance)
[1] 0.9764036
```

Mas lembre-se que essa é uma aproximação, e que para qualquer modelo de distribuição de erro diferente de `gaussian(link = "identity")` ela será enviesada.

O pacote [rsq](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rsq) implementa várias medidas de R² generalizadas e parciais. Pode ler mais sobre elas [neste link](http://statistics.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm) (em inglês). Mas é melhor simplesmente usar Critério de Informação de Akaike (AIC), que é robusto e comparável para qualquer modelo ajustado ao mesmo conjunto de dados.

Comment: Carlos, muitíssimo grato pela sua resposta, uma verdadeira aula. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: [Não precisa agradecer, apenas use o sistema de votação do site para indicar que a resposta foi útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Roberto Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 